# .NET Core TestServer returns status 200 instead of 404 for post request to non-existent path

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

I am implementing integration tests for a .NET Core 3.1 application using the following guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1. This is my current test class:

```
public class IntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<main_app.Startup>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<main_app.Startup> _factory;

    public TestTest(WebApplicationFactory<main_app.Startup> factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void GetBogusPath() {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("ofajspd");
        Assert.False(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void PostBogusPath() {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        var request_body = new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("ofajspd", request_body);
        Assert.False(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
}
```

The get request test acts as expected, in that it returns a 404 status code. However, the post request returns a 200 status, even though the path doesn't exist. What could be causing this problem, and how do I resolve it?

If I run the server locally and fire post requests at a non-existent endpoint manually, it acts as expected, so the problem is limited to just these integration tests.

EDIT: Here's my controller class definition:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class QueryController : ControllerBase
{
    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    public async Task<QueryResponse> Post([FromBody]QueryRequest rq) {
        return await QueryHandler.HandlePost(rq, this.HttpContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your controller method and route look like?

Comment: I've added the controller to the original question.

Comment: Is there anything in your startup class which might be injecting a response into the pipeline? What does your `Configure` method look like?

Comment: please share your start up configuration too.

Comment: Thanks @JamieTaylor, it turns out that some custom middleware that was there to capture a specific server error and suppress it was capturing a wider array of errors incorrectly, and so a 200 was returned instead of a 500. It's still not quite the 404 I expected, but this solves the issue posed in the question I think. If you want to frame your comment as an answer I'll be happy to give you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had attached a custom piece of middleware in Startup.cs that had a bug, so it was swallowing 404s generated by other middleware and outputting 200s instead. It was supposed to be handling a specific type of error, but the bug caused it to handle a much wider array of errors than intended. Removing the faulty middleware fixed the problem.

For extra detail, the custom middleware in question was checking for a specific 'HResult' in exceptions thrown by other middleware layers, but the HResult value referred to an AggregateException that was thrown much more often than the specific error I was looking for (which was writing to a response after it had already begun streaming).